# setup.iss file is not generated

Tags: installshield, silent-installer

I have a installshiled project which generates setup.exe file. I'd like to enable silent install by generating proper setup.iss file. I ran the following command:

```
Setup.exe /r
```

which lunched the installer, but it never created the `setup.iss` file. I looked in `C:\Windows` as the documentation suggested, as well as some other locations (local directory, program files etc.)

Why isn't it created and how to fix?

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, and a workaround:

The problem was that my msi project was a **Basic MSI Project**, as opposed to InstallScript and InstallScript MSI projects. This kind of project does not support reading a response file (aka setup.iss). However, there is a way to perform silent installation for the .msi / setup.exe file:

```
Setup.exe /s /v"/qn"
```

will do the trick.

All of this information can be found [here](https://wiki.csiamerica.com/display/kb/Silent-mode+installations)

Comment: Basic MSI projects can also be extracted with setup.exe /a. This runs an administrative install and creates an extracted installation source media. After that you can install the extracted msi with regular msiexec commands: msiexec /i name.msi /qn

Comment: how can we run application after the installation without a response file in silent installation.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to explicitly state where you want the setup file generated, using the `/f1` option:

```
Setup.exe /r /f1"C:\your\path\here\setup.iss"
```

Documentation on this [can be found here](http://www.silentinstall.org/InstallShield), but here is a summary from that link:

> Using the /f1 option enables you to specify where the response file is (or where it should be created) and what its name is, as in Setup.exe /s /f1"C:\Temp\Setup.iss". Specify an absolute path; using a relative path gives unpredictable results. The /f1 option is available both when creating a response file (with the /r option) and when using a response file (with the /s option)

Comment: Just adding emphasis, but that lack of a space between /f1 and the file directory is correct.  This command only works if you don't put a space after /f1.